# how to reload all partials on page refresh in HTMX

Tags: htmx

im trying out the HTMX lib and so far i like it alot. something that i cant quite get my head around is handling full page reloads.

Links

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" hx-get="/api/?action=feed" hx-target="#app" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-push-url="/#/feed">Feed</a>


<a class="nav-link" href="#" hx-get="/api/?action=profile" hx-target="#app" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-push-url="/#/profile">Profile</a>
```

its quite nice in that it loads the content in my required div, and applies a /#/link into my url bar and browser history.

But when i reload the page on any of the urls /#/profile or /#/feed the page reloads to its default state not including the content thats designated on the /#/profile or /#/feed pages.

If i just use a url of /profile or /feed, i get a 404 error as expected.

Everything is amazing, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For full page loads you would need to either:

1. Render the content server side
2. Use htmx with the `load` trigger to load the content on page load. You can find an example of that here https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/

In the second case you still need to be able to determine the type of page being loaded server side to render the appropriate div. Something like this:

```html
 <div hx-get="/api/?action=feed" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="#app" hx-swap="innerHTML"></div>
```